# What is the point of providing schema in case of reading a parquet using pyspark?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, parquet

When I am working with CSV, I can provide custom schema while reading a file, and the benefits I receive are as follows (along with the contrast with the parquet case):

1. All the rows do not have to be scanned through to infer the schema. (Parquet: Since the schema is stored in a separate file inferring schema is as simple as reading the schema from this file)
2. I can convert the schema of the file on the fly. For example, if I have stored integer numbers as a string(numbers) then I can provide the schema to read that column as an integer and it does. (This is impossible in case of parquet since it throws the `Expected: IntegerType, found: binary` exception in case the schema provided is of integer and the parquet column is stored as a string).

Given these two points, what are the benefits of providing schema in case of the parquet files?

Comment: Specifying a schema manually means no job is triggered for looking up the schema of the parquet file. This is a minimal performance improvement.

Comment: @ScootCork That's what I thought too. However, I wasn't sure. Thank you for your help :)